# ¿Cómo desarrollar una excepción para detener la agregación de números a un arreglo de números cuando se ingrese un string en C++?

Tags: c++, string, while, excepciones

Quiero hacer un código el cual almacene datos numéricos en un arreglo con punteros, y que se detenga cuando el usuario ingrese datos que no sean números (es decir, strings, o de no ser posible una palabra en específico)

Hice 2 códigos, ambos con problemas:

El primero cuando escribo la palabra "stop" se dispara hacia infinito

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void esNumero(){
  auto num = 2;
  int i = 0;
  int* vector = new int[1];
  string end = "L";
  while(end != "end"){
    cout<<"digite un número: "; cin>>num;
    if(to_string(num)!="stop"){
      vector[i] = num;
      i++;
    }
    else end = "end";
  }

  cout<<endl<<"Su arreglo es: "<<endl;

  cout<<"{ ";
  for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
    cout<<vector[i]<<" ";
  }
  cout<<"}"<<endl;
}

int main() {
  esNumero();
  return 0;  
}
```

Y el segundo no almacena correctamente los números en el arreglo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void esNumero(){
  string num;
  int i = 0;
  int* vector = new int[1];
  while(num!="end"){
    cout<<"digite un número: "; cin>>num;
    if(num!="stop"){
      vector[i] = stoi(num);
      i++;
    }
    else num = "end";
  }

  cout<<endl<<"Su arreglo es: "<<endl;

  cout<<"{ ";
  for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
    cout<<vector[i]<<" ";
  }
  cout<<"}"<<endl;
}

int main() {
  esNumero();
  return 0; 
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aún no tengo reputación para comentar así que adjunto mi respuesta, necesaria mente tiene que parar cuando introduzcas stop? o alguna palabra? no puedes agregar una pregunta al while de si desea parar de agregar números?

Comment: Es un ciclo en donde se colocan números, se detendrá cuando se escriba un string, es decir, se puede tener 2 opciones en cada ciclo, o adjuntas números, o escribes un string para detener dicho ciclo

Comment: Para empezar no puedes guardar cadenas en un vector de enteros a menos de que las conviertas antes, pero lo que te recomiendo es: 

que dentro del while tengas la función de agregar números al vector y luego de agregar un número preguntes

cout<<endl<<"Desea agregar otro número? "<<endl;

en caso de que sea entonces abres 2 case en el primero si dice si, entonces vuelve a agregar números y vuelves a preguntar y en caso de que sea no, el programa cierre o haga lo que necesites que haga, pero no guardes strings en cadenas de enteros